# How to load MobX data on store constructor, asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, mobx, mobx-react

I'm trying to write a MobX store which loads data asychronously in the constructor. The problem is, when I try to update the `@observable`, it doesn't fire the changes, so the React component is never updated.

That's the store (actually, the `setTimeout` is a server call):

```
class MyStore {
  @observable isLoading = true;

  constructor() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.isLoading = false; // won't update the React component!
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

This component blocks the app until the load is complete:

```
const MyComponent = ({store, children}) =>
  store.isLoading ?
    <div>Loading, please wait...</div> :
    children;

export default inject('store')(MyComponent);
```

How can I trigger the updates in the store constructor?

Comment: Is there a reason it needs to be in the constructor? Would it not make more sense for a default loading state, and having an action that will switch the state from true to false.

Comment: @WilliamChou It doesn't need to be in the constructor. Do you have an example of a different approach?

Comment: Mobx has a few ways to handle async, there's 
reactions: https://mobx.js.org/refguide/reaction.html
actions/flow: https://mobx.js.org/best/actions.html

action would be mapped to some event in your component or lifecycle hook.
reactions can be defined in your store constructor.

Some good examples to look at this in action can be found in the mobx real world projects: https://github.com/mobxjs/awesome-mobx#real-life-examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code provided your component is not marked as an observer, making it an observer should solve the problem. You can do it with `@observer` decorator provided by `mobx-react` package.

Notice that you should use [observer before inject](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react/issues/308)

Comment: Oh boy... I don't believe I'm stuck with this silly mistake for two days... thanks for noticing it.